# d3, draw arcs from source to target

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have an array of objects with source/target, generated from an adjacency list. It looks like this:

```
0: Object
    source: Object
        name: "test1"
    target: Object
        name: "test2"
```

I've plotted the nodes in a circle, like this:

```
var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
        .data(node_list) 
    .enter().append("circle")
        .attr("class", "node")
        .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
            return "translate(" + (Math.cos(2*Math.PI/node_list.length*i)*radius) +
                 "," + (Math.sin(2*Math.PI/node_list.length*i)*radius) + ")";
        })
        .attr("fill", "gray")
        .attr("r", 10);
```

Now I want to incorporate the edge data. Is there a way to tell d3 to draw an arc between the correct nodes?

Here is the code I have:

```
var arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .innerRadius([radius+20])
    .outerRadius([radius+40])
    .startAngle() //?? Usually I put something like d.x, but there is no "x"
    .endAngle() //?? same problem
```

Comment: You need to get a list of links in a similar way you're (presumably) getting `node_list` and then pass that to a line generator. See e.g. this example: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1153292

Comment: I would rather not use a force layout because I want the nodes to be arranged in a circle (which I don't think is possible in a force layout?). So absent the force layout I'm not sure how to get the necessary x/y values to draw the arcs.

Comment: You don't need to use the force layout. You already have the coordinates from arranging the nodes in a circle.